# How long can the prime chain $a_1=p$ , $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+4$ be at most?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

We start with a prime number $a_1=p$ and iterate $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+4$ until the next number is composite , for example starting with $3$ gives $3$ , $13$ , $173$ . Here the sequence terminates because the next number, is $29933=37\cdot 809$.

> Can such a prime chain be arbitary long ? If no, how many terms can it contain at most ?

The number $\color \red {306167}$ gives a sequence with $5$ entries. If we start with a prime below $10^8$, this is the maximum possible length.

Comment: For $p<\large {10^9}$, length $5$ still is the maximum.

Comment: Is fifth number composite or sixth?

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin The fifth is still prime, the sixth composite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No such chain can be longer than five steps; divisibility by $13$ is an obstruction.  Look at the iterates of the sequence $\bmod 13$ (and note that since $a_n$ only shows up as $a_n^2$ in the mapping, the result for negative residues is the same as for positive ones, so we only have to check residues $1\ldots 6$):

- $1\mapsto 1^2+4\equiv5\mapsto 5^2+4\equiv 3\mapsto 3^2+4\equiv13\equiv 0$ . This means that starting from any number $\equiv 1, 3,$ or $5\bmod 13$, a multiple of $13$ will be obtained in at most $3$ steps.
- $2\mapsto 2^2+4\equiv -5$ and immediately falls into the same path.
- $4\mapsto 4^2+4\equiv -6\mapsto 6^2+4 = 1$.

This means that after at most six steps (starting from a number $\equiv 4\bmod 13$), the iteration has to reach a multiple of $13$.

As for where $13$ comes from: while I found it by trial and error, there are a few quick filters that let the search be narrowed.  First, $-4$ (and therefore $-1$) has to be a residue $\bmod p$ for $a^2+4=0$ to have a solution, so only those $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$ need to be checked. Second, $-15$ has to *not* be a quadratic residue $\bmod p$; otherwise the map has a fixed point $a$ s.t. $a\equiv a^2+4\bmod p$. $13$ happens to be the first prime that meets both of these constraints.  The next is $29$, and it's not too hard to show that $0$ is in the orbit of every residue class $\bmod 29$ as well, but that takes a little more computation. I'm not sure whether the two conditions are enough to ensure that $0$ is in the orbit of every residue class, or whether there are primes $p$ meeting the conditions but with multiple distinct orbits of residue classes.

Comment: Oddly enough, divisibity by $5$ fails even though $-4$ is also a quadratic residue $\bmod 5$.  We get stuck if $a_n\equiv 3 \bmod 5$ because this is a root of $x^2-x+4\equiv 0$.  Luckily for us, $13$ avoids this trap by the discriminant of this quadratic form not being a quadratic residue $\bmod 13$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yeah, I was thinking of adding that to my explanation - thanks for the nudge!

Comment: @OscarLanzi To be honest, I hoped that the sequence can be arbitary long ...

Comment: @Peter It is better that it cannot.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin Because otherwise , we could not decide it ?

Comment: @Peter Someone probably could, but since this one is decided, now you can try to build examples where your chains of primes can be arbitrary long, if polynomial-like recursive sequences can accomplish that task.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin OK, thats a point.

Comment: There are two separate interesting questions here: (a) can such a chain be _arbitrarily_ long, and (b) can such a chain be _infinitely_ long? For instance, there are arbitrarily long chains of primes in arithmetic progression but no infinite chains; AFAIK it's unknown whether either of these can be true even for the 'simplest' non-trivial mapping $a_{k+1}=2a_k+1$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Whats the record for the mapping $2a_k+1$

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CunninghamChain.html