# New chain : $a_1=p$ , $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+18$ : What is the maximum length this time?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

Here :

[How long can the prime chain $a_1=p$ , $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+4$ be at most?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2475941/how-long-can-the-prime-chain-a-1-p-a-n1-a-n24-be-at-most)

it was proven that the chain $a_1=p$ , $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+4$ can at most give $5$ primes because we get a number divisible by $13$, and $13$ itself gives only $2$ primes. So, let us replace $4$ by $18$ to hopefully get a better recurrence relation. So the new question is :

> Can the sequence $a_1=p$ , $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+18$ be arbitary long if we let terminate the sequence as soon as the next number would be composite ? If not, what is the maximum possible length ?

The number $\color\red {463207469}$ produces $6$ primes and I did not find a better starting prime yet. So far, I did not find a prime $p$ either, such that the sequence must eventually run into a number divisible by $p$.

Comment: Since every $a_n^2$ is periodic $\mod p$, so for any $b$ such that $a_1 = p $ and $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+b$ will only produce finitely many consecutive primes that is according to smallest prime for any $b$, this somewhat is telling us that the smallest consecutive primes for any $b$ usually are the longest ones.

Comment: @Ahmad The periodicity doesn't show that we eventually have $a_j\equiv 0\mod p$, we can end in a cycle.

Comment: True for some primes, but talking about all primes it must hit $a_j = 0 \mod p$,taking the smallest of such primes, will determine the maximum number of consecutive primes.

Comment: But if we do not find a prime for which every start value will end in residue $0$, we cannot prove that only finite many primes can be produced this way. I think, what you want to say that there cannot be an infinite chain only containing primes, but the question is about arbitary long chains.

Comment: Yes, this is what i am trying to say, excuse my poor English, i still learn English.